# Django migration cannot create model table in DB

Tags: django

I have a model admin_portal.User. I can make migrations files for it, I can see 0001_initial.py under admin_portal/migrations.
However, when I run python3 manage.py migrate, I got

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin_portal, auth, common_app, contenttypes, knox, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying admin_portal.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying knox.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lexl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "auth_user" does not exist
```

In the DB, I only see these tables

```
                List of relations
 Schema |          Name          | Type  | Owner
--------+------------------------+-------+--------
 public | auth_group             | table | user
 public | auth_group_permissions | table | user
 public | auth_permission        | table | user
 public | django_content_type    | table | user
 public | django_migrations      | table | user
```

Why the user table is not created? admin_portal.0001_initial is applied, then 'auth_user' table should be created. I shouldn't have permission issue to create tables, right?

User model code:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, Base):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'supervisor'),  # user has all priviledges
        (2, 'admin'),
        (4, 'support'),
    )

    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True, max_length=256)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default=2
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'
        app_label = 'admin_portal'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.user_type == 1

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

Comment: How are your models defined? Could you add models.py in your post? You can try to remove your migration file and relaunch `makemigration`

Comment: @Christophe removing migration file and relaunch makemigration doesn't work

Comment: Have you set AUTH_USER_MODEL in your settings.py. If you are using a custom user model then don't forget to set AUTH_USER_MODEL.

Comment: @AkshayPawar I did